# Energy lost in a do-nothing machine

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, work, dissipation

I recently came across this large (and very cool) do-nothing machine:

[do-nothing machine (video)](https://i.imgur.com/hPhZEcc.mp4)

[image: do-nothing machine]

Commentators on the internet have mentioned that the machine wastes energy, and therefore doesn't "do nothing", but I'm not so sure.

The machine takes an input, in the form of electrical energy, and has no visible output. Parts move, but they don't go anywhere. The only outlet for energy I can think of is friction, which would cause energy to be "lost as heat". But modern climate controlled buildings make a point of spending energy to produce heat (at least when it's cold), so all this energy would be applied to a useful purpose.

Now, it clearly requires a fairly powerful electrical motor to run this machine, and it doesn't intuitively feel like the machine would put out very much heat. As a result, it does not feel like it would be possible to heat a building entirely with a bunch of these machines, let alone using less or equal energy then a heating system would.

But if that's the case, then where is the energy going? If 100% of the energy input in this machine is lost as heat, how could it be less efficient at heating a room than a heater using the same energy?

To distill the question two ways:

1) Is there any way for energy to escape this system other than being lost as heat?

2) If no to No.1, could a climate controlled building run one (or many) of these machines "for free", saving exactly as much energy as they dump into them?

Answer (score 0):

It will be exactly as efficient as a resistive heater.  Nearly every joule of energy which goes into it will be turned into heat (some energy will be spent on abrading the gears, which could put a small amount of energy into them instead of heating the room.

Now there *are* more efficient ways of pushing heat around.  Heat pumps can actually move heat from outside to inside more efficiently than a simple resistive element could have provided that heat.

That being said, its worth noting that when Bitcoin was at its highest, there were a large number of bitcoin miners setting up shop in places like Iceland.  Rather than having to invest in expensive HVAC equiment to cool the racks of processors, they relied on the ability to heat up the surrounding area when it was cold.

In the end, a lack of a net change in energy is not the same as any one component being "free."  If your environment changes, the rules change.  Personally, I live in a very hot climate.  We pay dearly to remove that kind of heat from our houses!

Answer (score 0):

1) The machine has no connection to the outside world other than thermal contact with the air surrounding it. So, it can't affect the world in any way other than to heat it up. The machine could do useful work if, say, you hooked up a wheel to one of the rotating gears and then putting that wheel in contact with the ground. Then the machine could drag itself across the ground, which would be actual work. But, all this machine does is heat up the air around it.

2) The machine does heat up the inside of the building, but it does so in an inefficient way. Heat pump air conditioning systems move heat from outside to inside instead of directly generating heat. So, in order to add 1 Joule of energy to the room, the machine has to use 1 Joule of energy. A head pump air conditioner would use less than 1 Joule. So, the machine is useless even as a heater since it uses more energy than required.